# Select 2 tables from 1 database in PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

What code can I use in order to select 2 tables from 1 database?

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\addeditdelete1\exec.php on line 19(this error is on,
$count=mysql_num_rows($result,$result1); )
```

**PHP code:**

```
include("dbcon.php");

$username=$_POST['username'];

$password=$_POST['password'];


$username = stripslashes($username);

$password = stripslashes($password);

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);



$sql="SELECT * FROM admininfo WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' and type='admin'";

$sql1="SELECT * FROM customerinfo WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' and type='customer'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

$result1=mysql_query($sql1);

//error in this line of code

$count=mysql_num_rows($result,$result1);

if($count==1){

$_SESSION["username"];

$_SESSION["password"];

header("location:menu.php");
}

else
{

echo "Invalid username or password!";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you think about SELECT UNION, for example

$sql="SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM admininfo WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' and type='admin') UNION (SELECT * FROM customerinfo WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' and type='customer') )";

That way you will have just one query with results from both tables. If table columns don't match, you can modify them using AS sintax in SELECT. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT username AS user, password AS pwd 
   FROM admininfo 
   WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' and type='admin')
   UNION 
   (SELECT username AS user, password AS pwd 
   FROM customerinfo 
   WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' and type='customer') 
)";
```

Comment: Sorry but Im a newbie in PHP and I dont know what is select union but i research a lot and found nothing working but im glad you shared what you know about this thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can find details on MySQL site : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't use mysql_num_rows with two parameters, you must call two time the function.

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result) + mysql_num_rows($result1);
```

I do not know your db schema, but it is very likely that you can do this job with a single SQL query.

Comment: tnx for the help, ill test this out :)